# How to prevent browser from opening a new page on form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

There's an **email subscription form** in a web page,
 When someone enters his email and **clicks on submit button**,
 We don't want this page to be redirected to **form action url**,
 We just want it's submit button text value **to be converted to another text**,
 something like "Thank You!".
 How is it possible? Should I go through ajax? or javascript?
Here's the form:

```
<form class="ml-block-form" action="//app.mailerlite.com/webforms/submit/myownID" data-code="myownID" method="POST" target="_blank">
<div class="form-group ml-field-email ml-validate-required ml-validate-email">
    <input class="newsletter-email" type="email" name="fields[email]" placeholder="Email*"/>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="ml-submit" value="1" />
<p>
    <input class="newsletter-submit" type="submit" value="Get Updates!"/>
</p>
```

Comment: remove `target="_blank"`

Comment: Change the input type from submit to button

Comment: And you don't want to post any kind of data? Just changing text? Or do you want to submit all data to the server without reloading and after a successful submit you want to change the text and maybe disable the form?

Comment: @axel.michel exactly! I want to change the text after a successful submit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters remove `target="_blank"` from your `form` tag.

Then, within your **jQuery**, do something along the lines of this:

```
$(".ml-block-form").submit(function(){
    var vals = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "postpage.php",  
        method: "POST",
        data: vals,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#formsubmit").val("Thank you!");
        }
    });

    return false; // prevent from submit
});
```

I've altered your **HTML** as well, as it was originally very messy. You can of course add the other elements back if you need:

```
<form class="ml-block-form" action="" data-code="myownID" method="post">
    <input id="mainval" type="email" name="fields[email]" placeholder="Email*">
    <input id="hiddenval" name="ml-submit" value="1" />
    <input id="formsubmit" type="submit" value="Get Updates!"/>
</form>
```

Comment: you could change data to '$(this).serialize()' to get rid of the variable declaration.

Comment: One more idea, if you use `$(this).attr('action')` as a value for the url in the AJAX part (and don't remove the original value from the HTML code) it would / could work with and without javascript.

Comment: @axel.michel possibly :) but I personally prefer it this way

Comment: I see no reason to disable basic functionality by removing a form action, and you should always to to be as DRY ans simple as possible. Using a hard coded URL in script code is harder to maintain and in most cases simply redundant.

Comment: Thank you, It solved the problem, But I don't know why the value of submit button doesn't change to "Thank You!" after hitting submit button.

Comment: @axel.michel as I said, it's just personally preference :/ you can do it how you want, and I'm sure this guy can change it. It's not hard set code

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove `target="blank"` because `blank` value opens the linked document in a new `window`.

Comment: This would still reload the page (not in a new window) but it would be a new page load which he wants to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<input class="newsletter-submit" type="submit" value="Get Updates!"/>
```

use

```
<button id="newsletter-submit" value="Get Updates!"/>
```

(note that I changed `class` for `id`)

And then use jQuery to handle the click on the button:

```
$("#newsletter-submit").click(function () {
    $(this).prop("value", "Thank You!");
    // do something else with the input values e.g. send them via ajax to a server script
});
```

Comment: A button has no visible value. Like this you would create an empty button. You can change the value though...

Comment: still wrong. In opposite to an input element a button contains text or other HTML tags, and this is what you see, so it has to be: `<button>Get updates</button>` and for the jQuery part `$(this).text('Thank you')`. Anyway this would still submit the form in case the user hits enter.